# building failure in jenkins as build.sh: not found

Tags: jenkins

I am building a free style project in jenkins. configure setting for execute shell script as

```
build.sh -label $JOB_NAME -$BUILD_NUMBER -java_home $JAVA_HOME
```

when i try to build the project, i have a console output as build failure.

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jmxweb
[jmxweb] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson4723307331600368596.sh
+ build.sh -label jmxweb -8 -java_home /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
/tmp/hudson4723307331600368596.sh: 2: /tmp/hudson4723307331600368596.sh: build.sh: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Are your sure that build.sh is in the Jenkins' workspace?

Comment: no , i just put the script into build from GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project)

Builds for Non-Source Control Projects

There is sometimes a need to build a project simply for demonstration purposes or access to a SVN/CVS repository is unavailable. By choosing to configure the project  as "None" under "Source Code Management" you will have to:

```
1 Build the Project at least once, (it will fail), but Jenkins will create the structure jenkins/workspace/PROJECTNAME/
2 Copy the project files to jenkins/workspace/PROJECTNAME/
3 Build again and configure appropriately
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running : $WORKSPACE/build.sh -label $JOB_NAME -$BUILD_NUMBER -java_home $JAVA_HOME

The error is definitely because it can't find the file where you're looking for it. explicitly specifying the path should make sure it'll look for it in the current workspace. 
Good luck!